# Why does "eggsecutable" search for __main__

Tags: python, executable, setuptools, egg

I try to make a executable `*.egg` file. I can create this using the following method: I just put a `__main__.py` at the top-level of an `.egg` named `.zip`, and  python will run that `__main__.py`

I have read that there is a more elegant way:

```
setup(
    # other arguments here...
    entry_points={
        'setuptools.installation': [
            'eggsecutable = my_package.some_module:main_func',
        ]
    }
)
```

https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#eggsecutable-scripts

But if I create ( with run `setup.py bdist_egg`) and run the `*.egg`, it prints: 
`C:\Python27\python.exe: can't find '__main__' module in <eggpath>`

So python doesn't find the entry point.

**Is it possible make an executable egg without explicit `__main__.py`?**

System:

- Win 7
- Python 2.7.9
- setuptools 39.0.1 from c:\python27\lib\site-packages (Python 2.7))

**UPDATE**

I have tried both on Linux both with python3 and I got the same error.

Comment: Do you have `main_func` in `my_package.some_module`?

Comment: Yes, it has. I have checked, by adding the `egg` to path, and I can import `my_package.some_module` and call `main_func`

Comment: I have the same problem under Win 10, Python 3.6.5 and setuptools 39.0.1

I am using a sample project as shown [here][1]

somehow, I am not able to automatically put a `__main__.py` at the top level of the egg. I put the `__main__.py` besides the `setup.py` but it ends up being moved to the package, so it's location inside the `.egg` is `example_pkg/__main__.py`


  [1]: https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like the entry points documentation is misleading and you don't need them.

What you probably want something like this:

`setup.py`:

```
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(
    name="example_pkg",
    version="0.0.1",
    # all the other parameters

    # function to call on $ python my.egg
    py_modules=['example_pkg.stuff:main']
)
```

`example_pkg/stuff.py`

```
def main():
    print("egg test")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

create the egg: `setup.py bdist_egg`

run the egg: `python dist\example_pkg-0.0.1-py3.6.egg`

output: `egg test`

solution source: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/distutils-sig/2015-June/026524.html